# Access Control Allow Origin issue and 405 method not allowed with asp.net mvc web api and Sencha Touch

Tags: asp.net, extjs

OK, co I have searched and tried what I think is everything. Basically I have an app I have built in Sencha Architect that uses a JSON proxy to call a Get method in my Web API. Running local host, not a problem, deploy to live, not a problem. Run localhost against live web api.. PROBLEM! :)

So, have spent the last couple of hours reading up on CORS and implementing Access Allow Origin in response header, even allowing "OPTIONS" in response header as part of the "pre-flight" check before trying to make the call and still no go. I have set request headers just in case in my call, but convinced this is not the actual issue. I get a 405 method not allowed, no matter what I do.

The crazy thing is, I just wanted to bundle this up as a native app and see if it worked... How does anyone else make a call to a public service using ASP.Net and IIS7.5 +?

Comment: Do you can access this service viar browser url?

Comment: Hi, yes I can no problem and the origin, methods and options all come through.... however, a breakthrough. Check out http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Implementing-CORS-support-a677ab5d/view/Discussions#content

Comment: Solved... Just check out this post here, add the Handler to Global asax and done... it serves my purpose here I wanted a public API.... Hope it can be of use to others...http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Implementing-CORS-support-a677ab5d/view/Discussions#content

Answer (score 0):

Move your sencha app folder in asp.net project folder and run sencha app using IIS server